# When will the .fini_array section being used?

Tags: linux, printf, objdump

I'm following http://tinyhack.com/2014/03/12/implementing-a-web-server-in-a-single-printf-call/ to write a web server with only printf() call.

I am following the guidance of the article.

Howerver, I found that the executable file of my program doesn't contain the .fini_array section with the help of objdump.

It is noticed that the .fini_array is defined by the Linux Standard Base Core Specification.

I read it and I'm curious about the relationship between .fini_array section and .fini section, how could they work together?

It seems that the .fini_array is not necessary. So when it is used and how should I continue my work?

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-1983/6mhm6r4es/index.html:

> The runtime linker executes functions whose addresses are contained in
>   the .fini_array section. These functions are executed in the reverse
>   order in which their addresses appear in the array. The runtime linker
>   executes a .fini section as an individual function. If an object
>   contains both .fini and .fini_array sections, the functions defined by
>   the .fini_array section are processed before the .fini section for
>   that object.

So `fini_array` is optional, and is a sort of fancier version of `fini`.

Comment: when will the compiler insert the fini_array section into the executable header?

Comment: It depends on the compiler, and the version of the compiler, and perhaps the exact platform....  It's not clear to me why this would matter to you.

Comment: I'm trying to do some shellcode things, the textbook told me to modify that section, while i cant find it.